# Visual Studio 2010 Show Clock In Status Bar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, statusbar, clock

Is it possible to show a clock in the Visual Studio 2010 status bar?  I miss it from VS6.  Perhaps an addin?

Comment: Hehe, the GUIs from 15 years ago were a bit bizarre.  Use the clock on the taskbar.

Comment: Actually I find the gui from 15 years ago quite a bit more efficient in terms of functionality and especially screen real estate.

Comment: Must be because screens were so much smaller 15 years ago!

Comment: Useful in fullscreen mode when your taskbar is hidden

Comment: i have a clock on my desk now. I know it is 20th century stuff.

Answer (score 0):

i found this : http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/net/new-features-for-the-statusbar-in-mfc/
which probably works for vs2010 as well.